# Passing argument parameter from Drupal Panel page into View in Drupal 7

Tags: views, panels, distributions

I am having issues using View display in a Panel, on Drupal 7 (using Panopoly), from one of the Pages in our Drupal 7 site. We are having problems passing parameters from Panels into Views.

I would like to allow passing the Taxonomy Name (in lowercase), from a Page (using Panels), to one of the Views on that page.
At the same time, I would like to pass the Taxonomy ID (tid) in the same manner.
Then, with Contextual Filters (which are used in the View), I would like to filter those news articles.

For example, it should allow both: 
**news/3** and **news/latest**, showing same results.

Could someone help me or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Install views content panes that comes with CTools. Create a content pane and set the argument input under pane settings.

Comment: Thank you John!

Actually, I am already using Views Content Panes. I am not sure how to pass the parameters as both Taxonomy TID or NAME to the corresponding View.. 

In the View I placed Contextual Filters, but they are either Tax TID or Tax Name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @nikreljin What would happen if a taxonomy term is named '7'?

Comment: That's a good point. We assumed that would not happen, but it could be the case of-course.

Thank you